# Is there a way to get a generic mp3 tag using mp3agic?

Tags: java, mp3agic

I'm developing an MP3 player with java, using [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) to edit .mp3 files metadata. The problem is: I don't know the specific tags of the files to edit the desired data.

Here's my code to get the mp3 track for example:

```
public static int get_rep(Music msc)
{
    try
    {
        Mp3File file = new Mp3File(msc.get_path());
            
        if (file.hasId3v1Tag()) 
        {
            ID3v1 tag = file.getId3v1Tag();
            return Integer.parseInt(tag.getTrack());
        }
        else if (file.hasId3v2Tag()) 
        {
            ID3v2 tag = file.getId3v2Tag();
            return Integer.parseInt(tag.getTrack());
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedTagException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (InvalidDataException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;  
}
```

Is there a way to get the tag value skipping `file.hasId3v1Tag()` and `file.hasId3v2Tag()` verifications?

I tried:

```
private static Object get_tag(Music msc)
{
    try
    {
        Mp3File file = new Mp3File(msc.get_path());
            
        if (file.hasId3v1Tag()) 
        {
            return file.getId3v1Tag();
        }
        else if (file.hasId3v2Tag()) 
        {
            return file.getId3v2Tag();
        }
        /*
        else if(file.hasCustomTag()) 
        {
            file.removeCustomTag();
            return file.getCustomTag();
        }
        */
    }
    catch (UnsupportedTagException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (InvalidDataException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

But I still have to check the tags, then cast the `Object` value to a tag value, which means I'd have to know it anyway. I'm accepting any suggestions, even exchanging mp3agic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID3v2` extends `ID3v1`, so you should be able to use `ID3v1 tag = file.getId3v2Tag();` and be able to extract ID3v1 data from it.

You could try this:

```
private static ID3v1 get_tag(Music msc) {
    try {
        Mp3File file = new Mp3File(msc.get_path());

        if (file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
            return file.getId3v1Tag();
        } else if (file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
            return file.getId3v2Tag();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```